# How do I find the integral of a function given the following information?

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

So I am trying to find the integral of the function above. I tried breaking it up in 3 different terms:

Integral of $xf(x^2)$ from 1 to 3

Integral of $3f(x)$ from 1 to 3 (I think is $3 * 7 = 21$)

Integral of $5$ from 1 to 3 (I think is $5(3) - 5(1) = 10$)

The problem is, I do not know how to approach the first one. I honestly have no clue. I would appreciate any help given. Thank you!

Comment: Try the substitution $u=x^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u=x^2$,

$$\int_1^3 xf(x^2) \, dx =\frac12 \int_1^3 f(x^2) (2x\, dx) = \frac12 \int_1^9f(u)\, du$$

I will leave the last step as an exercise.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

$\int_1^3xf(x^2)dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_1^9f(y)dy=\frac{7+13-6}{2}=7$, by letting $y=x^2$.